# Changing network interface of a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: azure

I've noticed that changing a network interface for a VM (with Ubuntu on it ) breaks the networking and leaves you stranded if you don't have a password enabled authentication (to use Serial Console).

1. I'm creating a new VM (Ubuntu 18.04).
2. Configuring the server
3. Then I decided to replace the network interface (from a VM that was shutdown)

   - it already had the IP (static) I wanted
   - it had the desired security group
   - and an internal dns entry
4. I stop the new VM, attach the new interface, detach the initial and boot up again.
5. VM starts fine but I cannot ssh any more.

I have found the following in the logs:

> [   12.038253] cloud-init[928]: 2018-07-16 14:21:49,325 -
>   stages.py[WARNING]: Failed to rename devices: [nic not present] Cannot
>   rename mac=00:0d:3a:2d:b0:71 to eth0, not available.

So the cloud init scripts don't deal with that correctly or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What were you trying to achieve? Tell us please step-by-step what did you do and what did you expect and what happened instead. This is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Let's say two nics here, nic1 is associated with an old VM which is stopped; nic2 is associated with a new VM. Now, you want to detach the nic2 and associate nic1 with the new VM, right?

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT yes, I just want to replace the NIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the test in my azure environment. It's likely that specific Ubuntu Server version does not allow to exchange the network interface. I change the network interface from **virtual machine-networking- attach or detach network interface** in the Azure portal.

Let's say 3 VMs:

```
vma is Ubuntu Server 17.10 which has a nic-a;  
vmb is Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS which has a nic-b; 
vmc is Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS which has a nic-c.
```

If I attach the nic-a to vmb, I can not connect to vmb using ssh by PUTTY.

If I attach the nic-a to vmc, I can successfully connect to vmc using the same way.

If I attach the nic-b to vma, I can not connect to vma using ssh by PUTTY.

If I attach the nic-b to vmc, I can successfully connect to vmc using the same way.

If I attach the nic-c to vmb, I can not connect to vmb using ssh by PUTTY.

If I attach the nic-c to vma, I can not connect to vma using ssh by PUTTY.

It seems that only Ubuntu Server 16.04 ssh work after exchanging the nic. Also,  Possibly It is because of **Netplan** influences. From this [blog](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2017/12/01/ubuntu-bionic-netplan), you can see

> Netplan processes the YAML and generates the required configurations
>   for either NetworkManager or systemd-network the system’s renderer.
>   Netplan replaced ifupdown as the default configuration utility
>   starting with Ubuntu 17.10 Artful.

More details about [Netplan Design](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan/Design) and [ReleaseNotes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_16.04_LTS).

Additionally, I suggest posting a question in https://askubuntu.com/ which is mainly for Ubuntu users and developers.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I was able to swap the network interface as I described in my question. Azure portal allowed to do that. It's the OS that doesn't cope with this too well from what I see. Can anything be done in this case?

Comment: Do you mean the Ubuntu 18.04 does not support to attach the nic or others, I am confused.

Comment: I haven't tried any other Ubuntu version distro. I'm just saying that after the Network Interface exchange (that Azure portal allows) I cannot use the VM any more because I cannot connect to it. So either something is not working correctly when the machine is booting up or this should be forbidden if it's not supported.

Comment: You're right, please see my update.

Comment: ok, that would confirm my assumption. I wonder if this can be corrected by a  special cloud-init script that Azure could provide for Ubuntu >=17 versions

Comment: Yes, you can give a feedback [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/using-cloud-init#), also, you can accept this as an answer so that others will take more attention to the same scenario. :)